# Android built-in animation not proper

Tags: android, animation, imageview, lag

I am trying to animate an ImageView with a background image. The animation loads fine during the first time but after that becomes laggy and no animation appears.

file ---- main.xml

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="Click me" />
```

file ---- TutorialActivity.java

```
      private isClicked = 0;
      private Animation animUp;
      private Animation animDown;

        animUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        animDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        animUp.setDuration(500);
        animDown.setDuration(500);

       Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                if(isClicked == 0)
                {
                    menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    menu.setAnimation(animUp);
                    isClicked = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    menu.setAnimation(animDown);
                    menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    isClicked = 0;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you use animation you should set animation start time. Any way you prefer, from simple `animation.startNow()` to more complex `animation.setStartTime(time); animation.start()`.